# styling issue when using custom bullets

Tags: html, css

I have this simple list like this

```
<ul>
    <li>....</li>
</ul>
```

And styling

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li:before {
    background-color: #1282CB;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 6px;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

The issue I have ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stu80zre/)) is that when the text in the list-item spans multiple lines it doesn't line up correctly with the other text on the left side [image: ist-item line-up issue]

When the bullet is positioned absolutely it works as I want ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stu80zre/1/)). Is it possible to fix this without an absolute positioned bullet ?

Comment: updated answer please check

Comment: Is there a reason why `position:absolute` is not an option? It's the standard method.

Comment: I want the bullet to be positioned in front of the the first line, in the middle (as it is now), without any knowledge of line-height and/or font-size. With absolute positioning this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `margin-left` from -15px to -12px. Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stu80zre/3/).

Answer (score 1):

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/stu80zre/9/

**remove position**

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}


li:before {
    background-color: #1282CB;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 6px;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -24px;
    top: 7px;
}
li span{
   margin-left: 15px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried with reducing the margin-left

```
li:before {
    background-color: #1282CB;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 6px;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stu80zre/7/